Unity HUB cannot load repositories
I am unable to load repositories in Unity Hub. Here is the imageenter image description here
Please help because i wanna work with someone for a jam and time is very less.
I have checked it is not a firewall or internet issue.
There is nothing more to add but to post the question i am writing this stuff. Please ignore _________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

Look in the log file, it will tell you what the error is
